how to add this hierarchial drop down menu in flutter
i am buildng a app which has categories, sub categories and sub-sub-categories, i want to do something like this in image
the third dropdown should be check boxes with multiple selections
what can i do. i am using listview builder for displaying primary list.
this is my code
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';

class LookingForScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const LookingForScreen({super.key});

  @override
  State<LookingForScreen> createState() => _LookingForScreenState();
}

class _LookingForScreenState extends State<LookingForScreen>
    with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  late final _controllerAddPriceBtn = AnimationController(
    duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 500),
    vsync: this,
  )..value = 1.0;
  late final Animation<double> _animationAddPriceBtn = CurvedAnimation(
    parent: _controllerAddPriceBtn,
    curve: Curves.fastOutSlowIn,
  );

  late final _controllerDetailsView = AnimationController(
    duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 500),
    vsync: this,
  );

  late final Animation<double> _animationDetailsView = CurvedAnimation(
    parent: _controllerDetailsView,
    curve: Curves.fastOutSlowIn,
  );
  @override
  void dispose() {
    _controllerAddPriceBtn.dispose();
    _controllerDetailsView.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var mQSize = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    var mQWidth = mQSize.width;
    var mQHeight = mQSize.height;
    return Scaffold(
      bottomNavigationBar: Container(
        color: Colors.red,
        height: 70,
        width: double.infinity,
        child: Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
          children: [
            TextButton(
                onPressed: () {},
                child: Text(
                  '0 Service Added',
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    color: Colors.white,
                  ),
                )),
            Text(
              "|",
              style: TextStyle(
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                color: Colors.white,
              ),
            ),
            Row(
              children: [
                TextButton(
                    onPressed: () {},
                    child: Text(
                      'Get Budget',
                      style: TextStyle(
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                        color: Colors.white,
                      ),
                    )),
                IconButton(
                    onPressed: () {},
                    icon: Icon(
                      Icons.arrow_forward,
                      color: Colors.white,
                    ))
              ],
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Container(
          margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 15),
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: [
              SizedBox(height: mQHeight / 15),
              Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                children: [
                  Row(
                    children: [
                      IconButton(
                        icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_back_ios),
                        onPressed: () {
                          Get.back();
                        },
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                  Row(
                    children: [
                      IconButton(
                        onPressed: () {
                          Get.to(NotificationsScreen());
                        },
                        icon: Badge(
                          backgroundColor: Colors.red,
                          isLabelVisible: true,
                          label: const Text("2"),
                          child: const Icon(Icons.notifications_none_outlined),
                        ),
                      ),
                      IconButton(
                        onPressed: () {
                          // do something
                          Get.snackbar('Clicked on ', 'Favorite');
                        },
                        icon: Badge(
                          backgroundColor: Colors.red,
                          isLabelVisible: true,
                          label: const Text("3"),
                          child: const Icon(Icons.favorite_outline),
                        ),
                      ),
                      IconButton(
                        onPressed: () {
                          Get.snackbar('Clicked on ', 'Profile');
                        },
                        icon: Image.asset(
                          'assets/images/profile.png',
                          width: mQWidth / 13,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              SizedBox(height: 10),
              Text(
                'Looking for',
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  fontFamily: 'Poppins',
                  fontSize: 22,
                ),
              ),
              SizedBox(
                height: 1000,
                child: ListView.builder(
                  shrinkWrap: true,
                  itemCount: 12,
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                    return Column(
                      children: [
                        Row(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                          children: [
                            Row(
                              children: [
                                Image.asset(
                                  'assets/images/graphics.png',
                                  width: 80,
                                  height: 80,
                                ),
                                SizedBox(width: 10),
                                Column(
                                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                  children: [
                                    Text(
                                      'Graphics Design',
                                      style: TextStyle(
                                        fontSize: 20,
                                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                    Text('Logo, flyer, poster, banner...')
                                  ],
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                            ScaleTransition(
                              alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
                              scale: _animationAddPriceBtn,
                              child: IconButton(
                                  onPressed: () {
                                    _controllerAddPriceBtn.reverse();
                                    _controllerDetailsView.forward();
                                  },
                                  icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_forward_ios)),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                        SizeTransition(
                          sizeFactor: _animationDetailsView,
                          child: Container(
                              //
                              ),
                        ),
                        Divider(),
                      ],
                    );
                  },
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

but i am unable to do . please help. 

You can use the ExpansionTile widget to achieve the functionality.
Example:
       ExpansionTile(
          title: const Text('ExpansionTile with explicit controller.'),
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
              alignment: Alignment.center,
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(24),
              child: const Text('ExpansionTile Contents'),
            ),
          ],
        ),


i have done this in an pet's cearing app, here it is how i made it done
first create Model for it
class PetCareService {
  String name;
  bool isSelected;

  PetCareService({required this.name, this.isSelected = false});
}

and utlize this code
class MultiSelectPetCareDropdown extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MultiSelectPetCareDropdownState createState() => _MultiSelectPetCareDropdownState();
}

class _MultiSelectPetCareDropdownState extends State<MultiSelectPetCareDropdown> {
  List<PetCareService> _services = [
    PetCareService(name: 'Grooming'),
    PetCareService(name: 'Vet Check-up'),
    PetCareService(name: 'Training'),
    PetCareService(name: 'Walking'),
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Select Pet Care Services'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: DropdownButtonHideUnderline(
          child: DropdownButton(
            hint: Text('Select Services'),
            isExpanded: true,
            icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_drop_down),
            onChanged: (_) {},
            items: [
              DropdownMenuItem(
                child: MultiSelectItemWidget(
                  items: _services,
                  onChanged: (selectedItems) {
                    setState(() {
                      _services = selectedItems;
                    });
                  },
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MultiSelectItemWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  final List<PetCareService> items;
  final ValueChanged<List<PetCareService>> onChanged;

  MultiSelectItemWidget({required this.items, required this.onChanged});

  @override
  _MultiSelectItemWidgetState createState() => _MultiSelectItemWidgetState();
}

class _MultiSelectItemWidgetState extends State<MultiSelectItemWidget> {
  List<PetCareService> _selectedItems = [];

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _selectedItems = widget.items;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return PopupMenuButton<int>(
      itemBuilder: (context) {
        return List.generate(widget.items.length, (index) {
          return PopupMenuItem(
            value: index,
            child: StatefulBuilder(
              builder: (context, setState) {
                return CheckboxListTile(
                  title: Text(widget.items[index].name),
                  value: widget.items[index].isSelected,
                  onChanged: (bool? value) {
                    setState(() {
                      widget.items[index].isSelected = value!;
                    });
                    widget.onChanged(widget.items);
                  },
                );
              },
            ),
          );
        });
      },
      child: Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          border: Border.all(color: Colors.grey),
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0),
        ),
        child: Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(
              _selectedItems.where((item) => item.isSelected).map((item) => item.name).join(', '),
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16),
            ),
            Icon(Icons.arrow_drop_down),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

